# Compare two nested lists and keep the union of elements

Tags: python, list

The title may be misleading. I will try to explain as clear as possible.
I have two set of lists :

```
a = [
      [(1.5, 13), (1.5, 16)], #first list
      [(5.4, 100.5), (5.3, 100.5)] #second list
    ]

b = [
     [(1, 2), (1.5, 3)], #first list
     [(5.4, 100.5), (5.3, 100.5)] #second list
    ]
```

I would like to compare `first list` of `a` with `first list` of `b` and so on. Remove duplicates if I found any. The final outcome will look like this :

```
c = [
     [(1.5, 13), (1.5, 16), (1, 2), (1.5, 3)], #first list
     [(5.4, 100.5), (5.3, 100.5) ] #second list
    ]
```

As you can see, `a` and `b` will eventually append forming `c`. However, duplicates will not be appended as shown in `second list` of `c`. Position is not mutable.

How can I achieve this efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to zip the two lists together, and [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) to remove duplicates from the concatenated pairs:

```
[list(set(x + y)) for x, y in zip(a, b)]
# [[(1.5, 16), (1, 2), (1.5, 13), (1.5, 3)], [(5.4, 100.5), (5.3, 100.5)]]
```

If you want to maintain order(sets are unordered), use a dict and get the keys with [`dict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys)(assuming Python 3.6+ for ordered dictionaries):

```
[list(dict.fromkeys(x + y)) for x, y in zip(a, b)]
# [[(1.5, 13), (1.5, 16), (1, 2), (1.5, 3)], [(5.4, 100.5), (5.3, 100.5)]]
```

For lower versions of python(dictionaries are unordered), you will need to use a [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

[list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(x + y)) for x, y in zip(a, b)]
# [[(1.5, 13), (1.5, 16), (1, 2), (1.5, 3)], [(5.4, 100.5), (5.3, 100.5)]]
```

If you want the tuples to be sorted by the first element, use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
[sorted(set(x + y)) for x, y in zip(a, b)]
# [[(1, 2), (1.5, 3), (1.5, 13), (1.5, 16)], [(5.3, 100.5), (5.4, 100.5)]]
```